# Non-editable Field names differ Between AGOL and File Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

While attempting to overwrite a hosted feature layer from a local featureclass, field.name "Shape__Length" cannot be updated using values from field.name "Shape_Length". When overwriting/uploading this line feature class the "Shape_Length" field name is changed to "Shape__Length". This is problematic because I am attempting to automatically update these fields in an arcgis desktop environment and then reupload the featureclass as a feature layer once again. The error is occurring specifically when using the a temporary layer from agol to update a file geodatabase feature class.

```
def workspaceUpdate(agolFeature, desktopFeature, workspace, fieldlist):
    featureClass = workspace + "/" + desktopFeature
    tempFeature = desktopFeature + "TEMP"
    
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(agolFeature, tempFeature, workspace=workspace)
    InsertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(featureClass, fieldlist)
    fcsearch = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featureClass, fieldlist)
    tempsearch = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempFeature, fieldlist)
    UpdateCursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, fieldlist)

    gisidfc = gistemp = updatelist = []

    with fcsearch as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            gisidfc.append(row[0])
    del cursor

    with tempsearch as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            gistemp.append(row)
            if row[0] not in gisidfc:
                InsertCursor.insertRow(row)
            else:
                updatelist.append(row)
    del cursor

    with UpdateCursor as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] in updatelist:
                UpdateCursor.updateRow(row)
    del cursor
```

error is;

```
  File "scriptfilepath", line 47, in <module>
    automate.workspaceUpdate(agolFeature, desktopFeature, workspace, fieldlist)
  File "scriptfilepath", line 25, in workspaceUpdate
    for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist. [Shape_Length]
```

The traceback points to the line; "for row in cursor"

```
    with tempsearch as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            gistemp.append(row)
```

I have looked into manually changing the field name in ArcGIS pro, but I've read it has something to do with file geodatabase properties and I was lead down a rabbithole with no solid answers. If there is a way to modify these *locked* field names in a temp layer just so I can update the field  in the file geodatabase that would atleast be a start to a solution. I don't believe manually changing the field on AGOL is an option, and if it was I am certain it would break the collection apps functionality as a result.